# Java Swing two form classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to have one class open by default, and then when I click a Swing button  I would like to have the other form run. I used to use Visual basic and it was so simple:

```
Form2.Show()
```

and

```
Form2.Hide()
```

But in Java, I can't find anything like that. Is there any way to do this easily?

Thanks!

Comment: You might not like this suggestion but your users will: don't do swap JFrames. Instead learn to show one single JFrame and swap "views" with a CardLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Study the following to see how pressing a button causes a new frame to display.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 
    new JFrame(){{  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
        setSize(300,300);  
        setLocation(100,100);  
        setVisible(true);  
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
        add(new JButton("PressToOpenNewFrame"){{  
           addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
               new JFrame(){{  
                   setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
                   setSize(300,300);  
                   setLocation(200,200);  
                   setVisible(true);  
                   setLayout(new BorderLayout());  
                   add(new JButton("PressMeToBeep"){{  
                      addActionListener(new ActionListener(){  
                      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
                         Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();  
                      }});  
                   }}, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
               }};  
           }});  
        }}, BorderLayout.SOUTH);  
    }};  
}
```

Comment: See also [*double brace initialization*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1958636/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `Form#setVisible(boolean)`

Answer (score -1):

```
frmMain1 f = new frmMain1();
        f.show();
```